# Followed Counts web part is blank sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, mysite

Followed Counts web part "FollowedCountsWebPart " is blank though the user has a personal mysite created?

Comment: It happens the same to me. Did you manage to solve it? I think it is beacuse of the User Profile Service

Comment: There isn't a lot of context here, so I am recommending this question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I resolved doing the following steps.

What I was able to do is:

1. Open Central Administration… Manage Service Applications…
2. Select the User Profile service application, but don’t click
   “inside” of it, just to the right of the text, so that the row is
   highlighted and the ribbon is shown
3. In the “Sharing” group of the ribbon, click “Permissions”
4. In this prompt, put in your service account that is running your
   Distributed Cache, and grant it full control

**Note**: Performing this action may cause the User Profile Services web services to be restarted, so it shouldn’t be done in the middle of the day.

Your newsfeeds should now be working and the Following webpart too!!

I hope this will help you!!

Cheers.